# Facebook Apps using PHP sdk

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

I am developing facebook apps. Can anybody help me how to get the friend lists who are using same facebook apps .and also how to send the notification to friends who is using facebook apps like. A is using "Facebook apps name" and start using it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for user list who are using app developed by you? If you looking to fetch user data of app which is not developed by you then its not possible ? Only the admin of App can see user list of respective app.

Please elaborate what you are looking to find ??

Comment: Yeah I am developing a facebook apps and I want to get the details of friends list of that friend who is using my facebook apps

Comment: So at the time when you ask your to accept permission you can get the user data like email and keep on storing that data in your database. Hope you looking for this else please elaborate more/.

Comment: I already got the details information of currently using the apps, and I stored the user information in mysql database.Can you tell me how to send the notification to that friends who is using my apps?

Comment: You cannot send message to his friends facebook doesn't permit that but you can just post on his wall and then his friends can see that he is using your App.